# Java method not waiting on BufferedReader input?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a `BufferedReader` waiting for input, but for some reason it doesn't wait for the second read and continues to print my third print statement.

Code:

```
BufferedReader inFromUser =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char letter,xVal;
int yVal;


System.out.println("Please enter a letter for your word.(a-z)");
letter=(char)inFromUser.read();  
System.out.println("Please enter a X location for this piece.(A-J)");
xVal=(char)inFromUser.read();
System.out.println("Please enter a Y location for this piece.(0-9)");
yVal=inFromUser.read();
```

Example execution goes as follows:
Please enter a letter for your word. //Waits on input here

a

Please enter a X location for this piece. //Doesn't wait here???

Please enter a Y location for this piece.

Comment: Both answers work perfectly and explain what I was doing incorrectly.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because once you press enter after typing a letter, you are also sending the newline character into the stream.

When you call `read()` the first time it returns the first character as expected. However, when you call `read()` the second time it will simply read in the newline character that is buffered in the stream, thereby seeming like it skipped over a read instruction.

The solution is to tell the `BufferedReader` to read the entire line, then fetch the first character from the line:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a letter for your word.(a-z)");
letter = inFromUser.readLine().charAt(0);
```

You may also want to improve upon this by doing some validation in case the user simply presses enter without inputting a letter.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it was not waiting is because `xVal=(char)inFromUser.read();` was reading the "\n" from the line `letter=(char)inFromUser.read();`

So one solution it to add an `inFromUser.readLine();` after each prompt:

```
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter for your word.(a-z)");
    letter=(char)inFromUser.read(); 
    inFromUser.readLine(); 
    System.out.println("Please enter a X location for this piece.(A-J)");
    xVal=(char)inFromUser.read();
    inFromUser.readLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter a Y location for this piece.(0-9)");
    yVal=inFromUser.read();
    inFromUser.readLine();
```

You add a inFromUser.readLine(); after each prompt, so it can read the "\n".